# CV2 imwrite not saving as16bit

Tags: python, opencv

Hi all I am working on a code which will save a numpy array of dtype=16, However when I am trying to save by cv2.imwrite, it saves as dtype=8.

```
print(pixel_array.dtype)

im=cv2.imwrite('result.TIFF',pixel_array)

im=cv2.imread('result.TIFF')

print(im.dtype)
```

The output for this code is

```
uint16
uint8
```

I tried with passing dtype for nd array.

```
 pixel_array=ds.pixel_array

print(pixel_array.dtype)

im=cv2.imwrite('result.TIFF',pixel_array.astype(np.uint16))

im=cv2.imread('result.TIFF',)

print(im.dtype)
```

Unfortunately second code also saving image as 8 bit, Don't know what am I missing here.

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992814/python-how-to-save-image-with-16-bit-channels-e-g-48-rgb?

Comment: imread loads by default as 3 channel  8 bit if you don't use the flags to load in original format.

Comment: Thanks @Micka that worked by giving a flag IMREAD_UNCHANGED